# Which is more official, Dragon/Dungeon magazine or the Compendium?

Tags: dnd-4e

If there is a discrepancy between the original source when it is *Dragon* or *Dungeon* magazine and the *[Compendium](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/database.aspx)*, which version of the content should be considered the most official?

When answering [How many attacks with Path of the blade ( from Dragon 381)](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/128785/28599) I was surprised that the confusion appears to arise from a slight change to the wording of the power.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any to consider the Compendium a rules source- it was set up and coded by an outside contractor, and often contains errors.  Path of the Blade is a relatively well known one, but there are others.  For example, it (and the online Character Builder) only give 2 of the traditions for hybrid monk, even though all of them are applicable.  Another such example is the Order Adept theme, where the Compendium gets the level 5 feature completely wrong for PCs who don't have spellbooks (this too is reproduced in the Character Builder).

The Compendium is in error on Path of the Blade, because the original wording is quite confusing- do the two attacks listed on the upper part of the power consist of the primary and secondary attack, or do you make the primary attack twice and each one gets a secondary attack tacked on?  The people coding the compendium tried to make sense of it, and changed the wording/format in accordance with their views.

Answer (score 4):

Both are official, but the Compendium presents the information with the latest updates and errata applied. As a result, that would be the most up-to-date and correct version to use.

Comment: For what it's worth, I generally assume, in the absence of any "official" statement to the contrary, that the later publication date supersedes the earlier.

Comment: What if I searched for this particular example and found no errata.  Would you think that the compendium would be in error in such a situation?  Or would you still assumes that its authority supersedes the older source?

Answer (score -1):

Both are, and so tread lightly read both thoroughly and always remember this the more specific rule takes precedence over the general rule. That should help clear up any confusion on which to follow.